# Retrieve Records from mysql that 90 days old in php

Tags: php, mysql

In my data base i have a column with name `date_time` ,type `varchar`. The date is stored via `$date_time = date('m/d/Y h:i a', time());` .

Now i want to display entries having `90` days old from my data base based on the `date_time` column.

I have tried this query

```
    mysqli_query($conn,"ALTER TABLE  table_name ORDER BY  id DESC");
      $beforedate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-90 days'));
    $result = mysqli_query($conn," SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE date(date_time)  >= date($beforedate) ORDER BY  id DESC LIMIT 200 ");
```

which showing all the entries in  the data base. How can i solve this

[output of query[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFYEt.png)

Comment: "with name date_time ,type varchar" - well, there's your problem.... Why do you store a date in a varchar field?

Comment: actually the work is started by another person he is stored it as varchar

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date_time) < 90 ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: which returns zero rows

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name 
WHERE date_time + INTERVAL 90 DAY <= NOW()
```

Comment: no its not working it returns zero rows